# LWC Date Picker - Year Display in <Lightning-input type="Date" >

Tags: lightning-web-components

Can I show  datepicker's year for just five years instead of showing 1919 to 2119?

Answer (score 4):

You need to specify the `min` and `max` attributes.

E.g.

```
<lightning-input type="date" name="input8" label="Date field with min and max values" value="2017-09-07" min="2017-09-05" max="2017-09-22" ></lightning-input>
```

See https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input/example